# Typoscript navigation with subpages

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I am trying to implement my navigation with typoscript and I am having problems to understand how to wrap right.

I already have a base navigation with 1 level that is working fine.
Now I have pages that has subpages and other that don't have.
For the ones without subpages I want the behavior that I have now.
For the pages with subpages I want to add this as an dropdown menu.

The HTML code should look like this.

```
<ul class="nav">
   <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            Test0
            <b class="caret"></b>
       </a>
       <ul class="dropdown-menu">
             <li class=""><a href="#">DropwDownItem1</a></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     <li class="active"><a href="#">Test1</a></li>
     <li><a href="#about">Test2</a></li>
     <li><a href="#contact">Test3</a></li>
</ul>
```

TypoScript:

```
  lib.menu = HMENU
  lib.menu {
  special = list
  special.value = 3,2

  1 = TMENU
  1 {
    wrap = <ul class="nav">|</ul>
    expAll = 1
    NO.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="">|</li>
    RO < .NO
    RO = 1
    CUR < .NO
    CUR = 1
    CUR.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="active">|</li>
    ACT < .CUR

    IFSUB = 1
    IFSUB.wrapItemAndSub= <li class="dropdown">|</li>
    IFSUB.ATagParams = class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"
    IFSUB.stdWrap.innerWrap= |<b class="caret"></b>
    ACTIFSUB = 1
    ACTIFSUB.wrapItemAndSub= <li class="dropdown">|</li>
    ACTIFSUB.ATagParams = class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"
    ACTIFSUB.stdWrap.innerWrap= |<b class="caret"></b>
    CURIFSUB = 1
    CURIFSUB.wrapItemAndSub= <li class="dropdown">|</li>
    CURIFSUB.ATagParams = class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"
    CURIFSUB.stdWrap.innerWrap= |<b class="caret"></b>
  }

  2 = TMENU
  2 {
    wrap = <ul class="dropdown-menu">|</ul>
    expAll = 1
    NO = 1
    NO.wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
  }
}
```

//EDIT: I have changed the code but now when I click on an item in the dropdown menu the ul class="dropdown-menu" is wrapped two times and the dropdown isn't shown properly.

Answer (score 4):

The option noBlur is removed since TYPO3 v6.0 and I read somewhere, that the RO state does something with javascript to show/hide the submenu - so I try not to use it. I rather do the showing/hiding via css.

I would've done it like this:

```
lib.menu = HMENU
lib.menu {
    special = list
    special.value = 3,2

    1 = TMENU
    1 {
        expAll = 1
        wrap = <ul class="nav">|</ul>

        NO.wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>

        CUR = 1
        CUR.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="active">|</li>

        ACT < .CUR
    }

    2 = TMENU
    2 {
        wrap = <ul>|</ul>

        NO = 1
        NO.wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
    }
}
```

Add the hover-effect via CSS:

```
.nav ul {
    display: none;
}
.nav li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: I think you need to add `expAll = 1` even to the first `TMENU`.

Answer (score 1):

The `<ul>` wrap of your subnavi should be around the `TMENU`. I don't think you need the `ATagBeforeWrap` as it only makes `linkWrap` within the `<a>` tag. So it should look like this (not tested):

```
lib.menu = HMENU
lib.menu {
  special = list
  special.value = 3,2

  1 = TMENU
  1 {
    wrap = <ul class="nav">|</ul>
    expAll = 1
    NO.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="">|</li>
    RO < .NO
    RO = 1
    CUR < .NO
    CUR = 1
    CUR.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="active">|</li>
    ACT < .CUR

    noBlur = 1
    IFSUB = 1
    IFSUB.wrapItemAndSub= <li class="dropdown">|</li>
  }

  2 = TMENU
  2 {
    wrap = <ul class="dropdown-menu">|</ul>
    expAll = 1
    noBlur = 1
    NO = 1
    NO.wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
  }
}
```

Here you can find good info about wraps, unfortunately it's in german: http://jweiland.net/typo3/typoscript/wrap-moeglichkeiten-und-hierarchie-in-menues.html

By the way: if you are using TYPO3 6+ the noBlur setting has been removed.

---> EDIT:

I shortened your code a little, but I really coudn't reproduce the problem. For me it's working fine. The li around the dropdown gets the dropdown class. But I don't see a duplicate of the `<ul class="dropdown-menu">`

```
  special = list
  special.value = 3,2

  1 = TMENU
  1 {
    wrap = <ul class="nav">|</ul>
    expAll = 1
    NO = 1
    NO.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="">|</li>
    RO < .NO
    CUR < .NO
    CUR.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="active">|</li>
    ACT < .CUR

    IFSUB = 1
    IFSUB.wrapItemAndSub= <li class="dropdown">|</li>
    IFSUB.ATagParams = class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"
    IFSUB.stdWrap.innerWrap= |<b class="caret"></b>

    ACTIFSUB < .IFSUB
    CURIFSUB < .IFSUB
  }

  2 = TMENU
  2 {
    wrap = <ul class="dropdown-menu">|</ul>
    expAll = 1
    NO = 1
    NO.wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
  }
```

Comment: It was me downvoting. I'm sorry, I should have added a comment. You don't use `wrapItemAndSub` on the items of the first `TMENU` which means that the whole second level `<ul></ul>` will never be **inside** the first level `<li></li>` as the question asks for.

Comment: Also, as with the @SimonSimCity's answer, you don't have `expAll = 1` for the first `TMENU` so the second level submenus will not be in the outputted code available to be used as dynamically appearing drop-down menus which the question seems to be about.

Comment: Thank you. This is working fine. But now I have a new problem. If I click on an Item on the dropdown the main dropdown item only gets the class <li class="active"> and not the <li class="dropdown"> and the dropdown <ul> is outside the <li>-Tag. Maybe it is possible to wrap with <li class="dropdown active"> if it has subpages and is active. I am using v6.1

Comment: Solved the first problem with ACTIFSUB and CURIFSUB but then the <ul class="dropdown-menu"> is wrapped two times if the current page is a subpage of the dropdown.

Comment: Could you edit your initial post or make a new question, so I can see the typoscript? Can't imagine your code right now.

Comment: I have tried your new code. But still the problem with the duplicate <ul class="dropdown-menu"> tag. And only this tag is duplicated. This is looking like this <ul class="dropdown-menu"><ul class="dropdown-menu"><li><a>...</a></li></ul></ul>. This only happen after a click on a subitem.

Comment: Any other typoscript? Like I said I can't reproduce the problem. Above code is working as expected.

Comment: Thank you very much. I forgot that I had an extension Template on this site so the navigation was created two times. Everything is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

This snippet I have used for internal page links:

I have used subtitle field for internal navigation.

for example:

> ```
> <a href="#about>about</a>
> <a href="#ourservice">Ourservice</a>
> ```

```
menu.main_menu = HMENU
menu.main_menu {

#special = directory
#special.value = 2

    1 = TMENU
    1 {
         wrap = <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">|</ul>
         expAll = 1
         noBlur = 1

         NO = 1
         NO {
            doNotLinkIt = 1
            allWrap.insertData = 1
           allWrap = <li class="first menu-{field:uid}"><a href="#{field:subtitle}">|</a></li>                      
          }

          ACT < .NO
          ACT {
               ATagParams = class="active dropdown"
               allWrap = <li class="active first menu-{field:uid}">|</li> |*| <li class="active menu-{field:uid}">|</li>
         }

         CUR < .NO
         CUR {
             ATagParams = class="parent_menu active"
             allWrap = <li class="first active menu-{field:uid}">|</li> |*| <li class="active menu-{field:uid}">|</li>
        }
    }   
}
```