# Navigation in typo3

Tags: templates, typo3

My Output with the Navigation, see below:

```
<div id="main_nav">

    <ul class="mainnav">
        <li>
            <a class="navlink_0" onfocus="blurLink(this);" href="top.html"></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="mainnav">
        <li>
            <a class="navlink_1" onfocus="blurLink(this);" href="sub1.html"></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="mainnav">
        <li>
            <a class="navlink2_0" onfocus="blurLink(this);" href="sub2_1.html"></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="mainnav">
        <li>
            <a class="navlink2_0" onfocus="blurLink(this);" href="sub2_2.html"></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My Navigation in the template:

```
page.10 {   
   subparts {
    main_nav = HMENU
     main_nav {
       entryLevel = 0
       1 = TMENU
       1.NO = 1
       1.NO.linkWrap = <ul class="mainnav"><li>|</li></ul>
       1.NO.ATagParams = class="navlink_0"

       1.CUR = 1
       1.CUR < subparts.main_nav.1.NO
       1.CUR.linkWrap = <ul class="mainnav"><li>|</li></ul>
       1.CUR.ATagParams = class="navlink_1"
       1.CUR.doNotLinkIt = 0

       1.ACTIFSUB= 1
       1.ACTIFSUB< subparts.main_nav.1.NO
       1.ACTIFSUB.linkWrap = <ul class="mainnav"><li>|</li></ul>
       1.ACTIFSUB.ATagParams = class="navlink_1"
       1.ACTIFSUB.doNotLinkIt = 0


       2 = TMENU
       2.NO = 1
       2.NO.allWrap = <ul class="mainnav"><li>|</li></ul>
       2.NO.ATagParams = class="navlink2_0"

       2.CUR = 1
       2.CUR < subparts.subnav.1.NO
       2.CUR.allWrap = <ul class="mainnav"><li>|</li></ul>
       2.CUR.ATagParams = class="navlink2_1"
       2.CUR.doNotLinkIt = 0

       2.ACTIFSUB= 1
       2.ACTIFSUB< subparts.subnav.1.NO
       2.ACTIFSUB.allWrap = <ul class="mainnav"><li>|</li></ul>
       2.ACTIFSUB.ATagParams = class="navlink2_1"
       1.ACTIFSUB.doNotLinkIt = 0
       }
          }    
}
```

This is what I want:

```
<div id="main_nav">

    <ul class="mainnav">
        <li>
            <a class="navlink_0" onfocus="blurLink(this);" href="top.html"></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="mainnav">
        <li>
            <a class="navlink_1" onfocus="blurLink(this);" href="sub1.html"></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="submenu" class="subsubmenu">
        <li>
            <a class="navlink2_0" onfocus="blurLink(this);" href="sub2_1.html"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="navlink2_0" onfocus="blurLink(this);" href="sub2_2.html"></a>
        </li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

Or to display it:

```
top1 | top2 | top2 ....
sub1 | sub2 | sub3 ....
       (eg)
     sub2_1
     sub2_2
     ...
```

What do I have to do in the template file of TYPO3? Sorry, I am a total newbee in TYPO3 and it is complicated.

Answer (score 0):

actually I think your target code is not semantically correct.
It should be:

```
<div id="main_nav">

    <ul class="mainnav">
        <li>
            <a class="navlink_0" onfocus="blurLink(this);" href="top.html"></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="mainnav">
        <li>
            <a class="navlink_1" onfocus="blurLink(this);" href="sub1.html"></a>
            <ul id="submenu" class="subsubmenu">
            <li>
            <a class="navlink2_0" onfocus="blurLink(this);" href="sub2_1.html"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
            <a class="navlink2_0" onfocus="blurLink(this);" href="sub2_2.html"></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

That is something you achieve with IFSUB.
See Examples here: http://www.typo3wizard.com/de/snippets/menus/text-menu-tmenu.html
and here: [Typoscript navigation with subpages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17078129/typoscript-navigation-with-subpages)